# How can I watch a github branch from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, github, github-api

I have a node process and I would like it to perform certain tasks when a specific GitHub branch is updated on a repository I own. I would also like to obtain a list of the changed files, but this can go into a separate question in due time. For now, if I could find a way to implement something like this, I would be very happy:

*In my node process*

```
var watched = new gitBranch('https://github.com/me/myOwnRepository#production')
watched.on('update', function () {
  console.log('new commit on my production branch')
})
```

I suppose I could poll the repo using the GitHub API, but I don't see anything in the GitHub API about fetching only a certain branch. Also, I would certainly prefer some sort of notification to polling, but again I haven't found anything like this for branches.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a down vote but no comment. If anyone else sees a problem with this question, please comment and I will try to edit it to make it better.

Comment: If you're not the owner of the repository, you can't set up webhooks on the repository: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

So, what you can do is poll. Try polling this endpoint: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository. Notice that you can use the `sha` parameter to specify which branch you want to list commits for. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will be the owner of the watched repository. I will edit the question

Comment: This is a very broad question. Github has webhooks exactly for this. You run a server and tell it on what action you want to receive notification and then handle it. You will have to filter by branch/notification/etc but this is no direct tool for this.

Comment: @tkone I did not know this, hence the question. I also had looked for, but not found, the webhooks. The accepted answer is exactly what I was looking for. Now I still don't understand why my question is too broad. I'm simply asking how to be notified when a specific branch is pushed to. What's broad about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use webhooks: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

The push event is what you'll be interested in: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent

Notice that the payload contains a "ref" attribute which tells you which branch was pushed to. Use that to do the filtering on your end (it's not possible to subscribe for events on a specific branch).